# Android startBluetoothSco not starting sco but isBluetoothScoOn returns true

Tags: android, bluetooth, headset

I have created a GitHub repo with a sample project that shows the below problem I am asking about here:
https://github.com/paulpv/audio-loopback/tree/simplified/app/src/main/java/com/twistpair/wave/experimental/loopback
(please stick w/ the “simplified” branch and disregard the “master” branch)

The two main files are:

- https://github.com/paulpv/audio-loopback/blob/simplified/app/src/main/java/com/twistpair/wave/experimental/loopback/MainActivity.java
- https://github.com/paulpv/audio-loopback/blob/simplified/app/src/main/java/com/twistpair/wave/experimental/loopback/AudioStateManager.java

**Disclaimer:** I am currently only using a single Samsung Epic SPH-D700 running CyanogenMod 10 Jelly Bean to code and test this with. I have not tried this on other devices, but maybe that might help stop me from pulling my hair out and going crazy.

I have been fighting getting Android Bluetooth SCO to **reliably** start and stop and capture/playback audio **FOR MONTHS**!
Once I can get the phone in to SCO mode, capture and playback via AudioRecord and AudioTrack (respectively) works fine as documented.
The problem I am having is that I cannot reliably get the phone in to SCO mode!

The examples on “The Internets” to use startBluetoothSco() and setBluetoothScoOn(true) all seem simple and straight-forward, but when I use them on my device they almost never reliably work.
I created my own test app that does nothing but start and stop SCO, and I cannot even get this to reliably work!

My code listens for a `BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED EXTRA_STATE==CONNECTED.`
I can reliably detect when any headset is connected or disconnected.

When detecting a connection my handler immediately calls startBluetoothSco().
A could swear that at least once this has kicked `SCO_AUDIO_STATE` to C`O`NNECTED, but 99% of the time it just results in a transition from `DISCONNECTED->CONNECTING->DISCONNECTED`.

Here is my annotated log output from my GitHub sample app:

```
10-03 17:00:13.970: I/dalvikvm(29487): Debugger is active
10-03 17:00:14.158: I/System.out(29487): Debugger has connected
10-03 17:00:15.779: I/System.out(29487): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-03 17:00:15.978: I/System.out(29487): debugger has settled (1325)
```

*My app starts w/ Jawbone headset turned off and updates the UI...*

```
10-03 17:00:16.568: D/MainActivity(29487): updateScreen()...
10-03 17:00:16.572: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()=false
```

*...UI update done*
*Sticky broadcast that tells me the current SCO_AUDIO_STATE...*

```
10-03 17:00:16.689: D/AudioStateManager(29487): onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED flg=0x10 (has extras) }
10-03 17:00:16.689: D/AudioStateManager(29487): extras={"android.media.extra.SCO_AUDIO_PREVIOUS_STATE"=2, "android.media.extra.SCO_AUDIO_STATE"=0}
10-03 17:00:16.689: D/AudioStateManager(29487): android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED
10-03 17:00:16.693: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> scoAudioStatePrevious=SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTING(2)
10-03 17:00:16.693: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> scoAudioState=SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED(0)
10-03 17:00:16.693: D/AudioStateManager(29487): android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED: SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED
```

*...current SCO_AUDIO_STATE == DISCONNECTED; expected, since my headset is turned off.*
*My SCO Disconnected event listener is called and updates the UI w/ two sendMessages...*

```
10-03 17:00:16.693: I/MainActivity(29487): onAudioManagerScoAudioDisconnected()
10-03 17:00:16.755: D/libEGL(29487): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-03 17:00:16.787: D/libEGL(29487): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-03 17:00:16.791: D/libEGL(29487): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
10-03 17:00:16.888: D/OpenGLRenderer(29487): Enabling debug mode 0
10-03 17:00:16.912: D/MainActivity(29487): MSG_UPDATE_BLUETOOTH_INDICATION
10-03 17:00:16.912: D/MainActivity(29487): updateScreen()...
10-03 17:00:16.912: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()=false
10-03 17:00:16.927: D/MainActivity(29487): MSG_UPDATE_AUDIO_OUTPUT_STREAM_TYPE
10-03 17:00:16.927: D/MainActivity(29487): updateScreen()...
10-03 17:00:16.931: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()=false
```

*...UI update done*

*After ~20 seconds I turn on my Jawbone headset...*

```
10-03 17:00:37.572: D/AudioStateManager(29487): onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x10 (has extras) }
10-03 17:00:37.583: D/AudioStateManager(29487): extras={"android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE"=00:21:3C:00:3E:02, "android.bluetooth.profile.extra.PREVIOUS_STATE"=0, "android.bluetooth.profile.extra.STATE"=1}
10-03 17:00:37.587: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mReceiver: BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
10-03 17:00:37.587: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> bluetoothDevice=00:21:3C:00:3E:02
10-03 17:00:37.587: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> bluetoothHeadsetStatePrevious=STATE_DISCONNECTED(0)
10-03 17:00:37.587: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> bluetoothHeadsetState=STATE_CONNECTING(1)
10-03 17:00:37.619: D/AudioStateManager(29487): onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x10 (has extras) }
10-03 17:00:37.623: D/AudioStateManager(29487): extras={"android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE"=00:21:3C:00:3E:02, "android.bluetooth.profile.extra.PREVIOUS_STATE"=1, "android.bluetooth.profile.extra.STATE"=2}
10-03 17:00:37.623: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mReceiver: BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
10-03 17:00:37.623: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> bluetoothDevice=00:21:3C:00:3E:02
10-03 17:00:37.626: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> bluetoothHeadsetStatePrevious=STATE_CONNECTING(1)
10-03 17:00:37.626: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> bluetoothHeadsetState=STATE_CONNECTED(2)
```

*Jawbone connected; My event listener is called...*

```
10-03 17:00:37.626: I/MainActivity(29487): onBluetoothHeadsetConnected()
```

*...sees that we can SCO...*

```
10-03 17:00:37.626: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoAvailableOffCall()=true
```

*...and auto-calls startBluetoothSco()*
**HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS! Why does this call to startBluetoothSco not result in SCO_AUDIO_STATE == CONNECTED?!?!**

```
10-03 17:00:37.626: D/AudioStateManager(29487): startBluetoothSco()
10-03 17:00:37.626: I/AudioStateManager(29487): mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
```

*My event listener finishes up w/ a sendMessage to update the UI w/ the current BT state...*

```
10-03 17:00:37.646: D/MainActivity(29487): MSG_UPDATE_BLUETOOTH_INDICATION
10-03 17:00:37.650: D/MainActivity(29487): updateScreen()...
10-03 17:00:37.650: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()=false
```

*...UI update done*
*First result from startBluetoothSco comes in...*

```
10-03 17:00:37.681: D/AudioStateManager(29487): onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED flg=0x10 (has extras) }
10-03 17:00:37.681: D/AudioStateManager(29487): extras={"android.media.extra.SCO_AUDIO_STATE"=2, "android.media.extra.SCO_AUDIO_PREVIOUS_STATE"=0}
10-03 17:00:37.681: D/AudioStateManager(29487): android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED
10-03 17:00:37.685: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> scoAudioStatePrevious=SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED(0)
10-03 17:00:37.685: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> scoAudioState=SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTING(2)
```

*...moved from DISCONNECTED to CONNECTING*
*Second result from startBluetoothSco comes in...*

```
10-03 17:00:37.759: D/AudioStateManager(29487): onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED flg=0x10 (has extras) }
10-03 17:00:37.763: D/AudioStateManager(29487): extras={"android.media.extra.SCO_AUDIO_STATE"=0, "android.media.extra.SCO_AUDIO_PREVIOUS_STATE"=2}
10-03 17:00:37.763: D/AudioStateManager(29487): android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED
10-03 17:00:37.763: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> scoAudioStatePrevious=SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTING(2)
10-03 17:00:37.763: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> scoAudioState=SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED(0)
10-03 17:00:37.763: D/AudioStateManager(29487): android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED: SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED
```

*...moved from CONNECTING to **DISCONNECTED***
*I would have expected SCO to go from CONNECTING to **CONNECTED**!*
*My event listener is called and updates the UI w/ two sendMessages...*

```
10-03 17:00:37.763: I/MainActivity(29487): onAudioManagerScoAudioDisconnected()
10-03 17:00:37.767: D/MainActivity(29487): MSG_UPDATE_BLUETOOTH_INDICATION
10-03 17:00:37.767: D/MainActivity(29487): updateScreen()...
10-03 17:00:37.767: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()=false
10-03 17:00:37.783: D/MainActivity(29487): MSG_UPDATE_AUDIO_OUTPUT_STREAM_TYPE
10-03 17:00:37.783: D/MainActivity(29487): updateScreen()...
10-03 17:00:37.783: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()=false
```

*...UI update done*

*I wait ~20 seconds for SCO connected but it never comes.*
*I press my app's "startBluetoothSco" button.*
**NOTE THAT THIS RESULTS IN THE EXACT SAME CALL TO startBluetoothSco() AT 17:00:37.626**

```
10-03 17:01:01.689: D/AudioStateManager(29487): startBluetoothSco()
10-03 17:01:01.689: I/AudioStateManager(29487): mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
```

*First result from startBluetoothSco comes in...*

```
10-03 17:01:01.708: D/AudioStateManager(29487): onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED flg=0x10 (has extras) }
10-03 17:01:01.712: D/AudioStateManager(29487): extras={"android.media.extra.SCO_AUDIO_STATE"=2, "android.media.extra.SCO_AUDIO_PREVIOUS_STATE"=0}
10-03 17:01:01.712: D/AudioStateManager(29487): android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED
10-03 17:01:01.712: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> scoAudioStatePrevious=SCO_AUDIO_STATE_DISCONNECTED(0)
10-03 17:01:01.712: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> scoAudioState=SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTING(2)
```

*...moved from DISCONNECTED to CONNECTING*
**Here is where things differ from the auto-call of startBluetoothSco() at 17:00:37.626**
*We get a **BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED** event...*

```
10-03 17:01:01.716: D/AudioStateManager(29487): onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x10 (has extras) }
10-03 17:01:01.720: D/AudioStateManager(29487): extras={"android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE"=00:21:3C:00:3E:02, "android.bluetooth.profile.extra.PREVIOUS_STATE"=10, "android.bluetooth.profile.extra.STATE"=11}
10-03 17:01:01.720: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mReceiver: BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
10-03 17:01:01.720: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> bluetoothDevice=00:21:3C:00:3E:02
10-03 17:01:01.720: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> bluetoothHeadsetAudioStatePrevious=STATE_AUDIO_DISCONNECTED(10)
10-03 17:01:01.720: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> bluetoothHeadsetAudioState=STATE_AUDIO_CONNECTING(11)
```

*...moved from DISCONNECTED to CONNECTING*
*We get another BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED event...*

```
10-03 17:01:02.572: D/AudioStateManager(29487): onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.bluetooth.headset.profile.action.AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED flg=0x10 (has extras) }
10-03 17:01:02.576: D/AudioStateManager(29487): extras={"android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE"=00:21:3C:00:3E:02, "android.bluetooth.profile.extra.PREVIOUS_STATE"=11, "android.bluetooth.profile.extra.STATE"=12}
10-03 17:01:02.576: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mReceiver: BluetoothHeadset.ACTION_AUDIO_STATE_CHANGED
10-03 17:01:02.576: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> bluetoothDevice=00:21:3C:00:3E:02
10-03 17:01:02.576: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> bluetoothHeadsetAudioStatePrevious=STATE_AUDIO_CONNECTING(11)
10-03 17:01:02.580: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> bluetoothHeadsetAudioState=STATE_AUDIO_CONNECTED(12)
```

*...moved from CONNECTING to CONNECTED*
*Event updates the UI w/ one sendMessage*

```
10-03 17:01:02.580: I/MainActivity(29487): onBluetoothHeadsetAudioConnected()
10-03 17:01:02.580: D/MainActivity(29487): MSG_UPDATE_BLUETOOTH_INDICATION
10-03 17:01:02.580: D/MainActivity(29487): updateScreen()...
10-03 17:01:02.583: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()=true
```

*...UI update done (To be honest, I am not sure what is calling isBluetoothScoOn a second time)*

```
10-03 17:01:02.603: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()=true
```

*Second result from startBluetoothSco comes in...*

```
10-03 17:01:02.603: D/AudioStateManager(29487): onReceive: intent=Intent { act=android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED flg=0x10 (has extras) }
10-03 17:01:02.607: D/AudioStateManager(29487): extras={"android.media.extra.SCO_AUDIO_STATE"=1, "android.media.extra.SCO_AUDIO_PREVIOUS_STATE"=2}
10-03 17:01:02.607: D/AudioStateManager(29487): android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED
10-03 17:01:02.607: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> scoAudioStatePrevious=SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTING(2)
10-03 17:01:02.607: D/AudioStateManager(29487): ==> scoAudioState=.SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED(1)
10-03 17:01:02.607: D/AudioStateManager(29487): android.media.ACTION_SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATED: SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED
```

*...moved from CONNECTING to CONNECTED*

**FINALLY!**
*My event listener is called and updates the UI w/ two sendMessages...*

```
10-03 17:01:02.611: I/MainActivity(29487): onAudioManagerScoAudioConnected()
10-03 17:01:02.630: D/MainActivity(29487): MSG_UPDATE_BLUETOOTH_INDICATION
10-03 17:01:02.630: D/MainActivity(29487): updateScreen()...
10-03 17:01:02.634: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()=true
10-03 17:01:02.650: D/MainActivity(29487): MSG_UPDATE_AUDIO_OUTPUT_STREAM_TYPE
10-03 17:01:02.650: D/MainActivity(29487): updateScreen()...
10-03 17:01:02.650: D/AudioStateManager(29487): mAudioManager.isBluetoothScoOn()=true
```

*...UI update done*

**Everything (this time) works when I "manually" start SCO after some time, but not if I automatically start SCO immediately after a headset is connected.**

To make things worse, when things aren't working as expected I see strange behavior in the SCO states:

- Delaying the startBluetoothSco() for a resonable 3-5 seconds seems to make no difference. I haven't tried delaying it any more than 5 seconds. Waiting more than 5 seconds for audio to start flowing to your BT headset is ridiculous.
- Sometimes calling isBluetoothScoOn() returns true, even when I have never received a broadcast event since the last DISCONNECTED state saying that state changed to CONNECTED.
- Sometimes "manually" calling startBluetoothSco() from the UI does nothing, as if SCO is already on, yet I never received any broadcast event since the last DISCONNECTED state saying that state changed to CONNECTED.
- Trying to open AudioTrack or AudioRecord results in no sound (this same code works fine when SCO isn't misbehaving. ie: the problem is the SCO state, not the AudioTrack/AudioRecord calls).
- Calling stopBluetoothSco() does not result in any event reporting state DISCONNECTED.
- setBluetoothScoOn(false/true) makes no difference. To be honest I don't understand the difference in the seemingly redundant "startBluetoothSco()/stopBluetoothSco()" and "setBluetoothScoOn(boolean)". When things work, my calling startBluetoothSco() results in isBluetoothScoOn() returning true making me think that I don't need to call setBluetoothScoOn(true).
- Rebooting the phone makes no difference.
- Rebooting the headset makes no difference.
- Changing to another headset makes no difference.
- Sometimes the headset loses its pairing and has to be re-paired.

Given Google's/Android's track record on Bluetooth support, very little of this surprises me.

Can someone please put me out of my misery and definitely explain how to reliably start and stop bluetooth SCO in Android?

PS: Is there an official channel to escalate issues like this [w/ Google? Samsung?]? Or, is StackOverflow my best chance of finding an actual answer?

Comment: I have run this same code against a Motorola RAZR running ICS and it has the exact same or worse results.  
On this Motorola RAZR I cannot even "manually" get startBluetoothSco() to go from SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTING->SCO_AUDIO_STATE_CONNECTED.

Comment: I also tried this on both a Samsung HM1700 headset and a Jawbone non-A2DP headset.
Different phones, different headsets; Exact same [or worse] results. :(

Comment: I have the exact issue , I can only tell you that I have a similar code to yours that works on Samsung Galaxy Mini with Gingerbread and it works but the same code doesn't work at all on Jellybean .

Comment: BTW,when testing on the Gingerbread I never see any SCO_AUDIO_STATE_UPDATES at all but I can record some voice and play it back without problems !!

Comment: I had the same problems for a while, but now I figured it out. You have to called stopBluetoothSco for it to work.

Comment: Wow! So I am not the only one that this happens to! :)

Comment: You are not the only one with this problem. I am wondering why and how there can be apps without any Bluetooth SCO errors. Hm, wait: Are there any? We are trying to fix audio routing for the different devices for months, too. Up to now, we thought that we must be silly not to fix it, and that we did not really understand how Android should handle this. But I am sure for today, that we have tried everything, and there is no "right handling" in code - we are damned to write workaround on workaround on workaround for each silly behaving device!

Comment: 2020 and we still have the same issue

Comment: 10 years later I am still running in to similar issues as this with Android BT audio microphone recording. Sheesh! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many things missing in the Android documentation, however, if you call startBluetoothSco() and stopBluetoothSco() each time during audio routing there should be no problem routing the audio properly.
Even I have seen when the connection is kept idle for long and we start StartBluetoothSco() we directly get disconnection.
To solve this I wrote a workaround which is here:  https://github.com/kodered/Bluetooth-Refresh-Logic

Hope this helps.

Comment: After two years of no answer, I haven't tested your solution, but I am going to give you credit for this one!